# Inner class failed to access the mocked outer class method

Tags: java, mockito, inner-classes

Here are the sample class to be test:

```
public class TestOuterClass {
  private final InnerClass innerObj;

  boolean status;
  Object nullObj = null;

  public TestOuterClass(boolean status) {
    this.innerObj = new InnerClass();
    this.status = status;
  }

  public class InnerClass {
    public boolean doInner() {
      return outerMethod();
    }
  }

  public void mockOuterMethod() {
    if (innerObj.doInner()) {
      return;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException();
  }

  boolean outerMethod() {
    nullObj.toString();
    return status;
  }
}
```

The following is the example test code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TestOuterClass.class)
public class TestMockOuterClass {
  @Test
  public void testMockOuterMethod() {
    TestOuterClass outerObj = spy(new TestOuterClass(false));
    doReturn(true).when(outerObj).outerMethod();
    outerObj.mockOuterMethod();
  }

  @Test
  public void testOuterMethod() {
    TestOuterClass outerObj = spy(new TestOuterClass(false));
    doReturn(true).when(outerObj).outerMethod();
    assertTrue(outerObj.outerMethod());
  }
}
```

Note that the first test fails with the following exception stack and the second one succeeds:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.samza.runtime.TestOuterClass.outerMethod(TestOuterClass.java:31)
at org.apache.samza.runtime.TestOuterClass$InnerClass.doInner(TestOuterClass.java:19)
at org.apache.samza.runtime.TestOuterClass.mockOuterMethod(TestOuterClass.java:24)
at org.apache.samza.runtime.TestMockOuterClass.testMockOuterMethod(TestMockOuterClass.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:316)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:300)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:288)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:208)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:121)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:123)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

It seems like when I created a spy object for class `TestOuterClass` and directly mock and test the `outerMethod`, it worked. However, the mock does not work when the `outerMethod` is triggered from `InnerClass.doInner()` method. What's the recommended way to fix the first test?

Comment: Just to add more clarification to this problem. It is actually related to the sequence of how objects are constructed via spy(new TestOuterClass()). The problem is: the mocked method is applied to the spy(new TestOuterClass()), not to the InnerClass object which is created in the constructor of TestOuterClass() before spy() is applied. When I move the creation of InnerClass object in the method TestOuterClass.mockOuterMethod(), both tests passed as well. For InnerClass objects you only want to generate once, use the injection method described in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through this example point by point.

In the test case, you create a spy around an instance of `TestOuterClass`. While creating the instance (in the constructor) you create an object of `InnerClass` as its field.

Now you mock the behaviour of the `outerMethod` to make it always return `true`.

Now, what happens when `outerObj.mockOuterMethod()` is called is that the **real** method is being called as it is not mocked. You can see it in the stacktrace which you provided:

```
at org.apache.samza.runtime.TestOuterClass.outerMethod(TestOuterClass.java:31)
at org.apache.samza.runtime.TestOuterClass$InnerClass.doInner(TestOuterClass.java:19)
at org.apache.samza.runtime.TestOuterClass.mockOuterMethod(TestOuterClass.java:24)
```

Later, it just goes on calling the real `doInner` method - and here is where it could be confusing - the real `outerMethod`.

You might say: "Hey, I've mocked that thing". But you see - in this method:

```
public boolean doInner() {
  return outerMethod();
}
```

You are actually refering to `this.outherMethod()`. The problem is that from the point of view of `InnerClass`, `this` refers to the actuall `TestOuterClass` instance - **not** the spy.

When you create a spy of an instance, a sort of proxy is being created. When you call a method which was mocked, then the real object won't be even reached. **But** when you call a method which was not mocked - it will "proxy" the call to the real object.

So your question is: how to fix it?

You can add another constructor of `TestOuterClass` in which instead of creating the instance of InnerClass you would inject it:

```
public TestOuterClass(boolean status, InnerClass innerObj) {
    this.innerObj = innerObj;
    this.status = status;
}
```

Then, in the tests you can create pass a mock of `InnerClass` to the constructor:

```
TestOuterClass.InnerClass innerObjMock = Mockito.mock(TestOuterClass.InnerClass.class);
TestOuterClass outerObj = spy(new TestOuterClass(false, innerObjMock));
```

With this setup you can simulate the behaviour of the `innerObjMock`.

If this is not something you were looking for, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I found out through debugging the test as well. The injection method is exactly what I finally used to solve the test case.